# How to Group By on a list of strings in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

My Data

```
Column 1       Column 2                              Column 3
"Task 1"       ["emailofowner1","emailofowner2"]      John Doe
"Task 37"      ["emailofowner1","emailofowner2"]      John Doe
```

I have many such rows I want my output to be :

```
Column 1                 Column 2                            Column 3
["Task1","Task37"]       ["emailofowner1","emailofowner2"]     John Doe
```

Comment: Wouldn't column 1 of output be task 37 in your example data instead of task 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) requires hashable objects, which list aren't.

You can convert to tuple to use as a grouper:

```
out = (df
  .groupby(df['Column 2'].apply(tuple), as_index=False)
  .agg({'Column 1': list, 'Column 2': 'first', 'Column 3': 'first'})
)
```

Output:

```
            Column 1                        Column 2  Column 3
0  [Task 1, Task 37]  [emailofowner1, emailofowner2]  John Doe
```

Comment: works like a charm, thank you. One question can I include multiple columns in groupby?

Comment: @Suyash yes, use a list of Series / column name

Comment: for example what to do if I want column 3 in group by? do I pass it as a tuple too?

Comment: `.groupby([df['Column 2'].apply(tuple), 'Column 3'])`